# Is there a wordpress plugin or a script for sharing the exact/live location of a user and send it using contact form?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, geolocation, contact-form-7

I am making a website for a road assistance company, and I'd like your help.
I want to have a contact form and let the user who needs assistance send his live location like WhatsApp/Messenger/Viber do?

Comment: You dont need a plugin for this. Just get create a form by hand or Contact Form 7 or whichever tool. Then use the examples here to fill in a hidden or not hidden field in the form https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp
the user will be prompted if he allows geolocation.
this will use the best possible location, if GPS is available, it will use GPS data

Comment: I will try it out! Massive thanks mate!